# How to combine two data fields in a database and display in a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a query to get data in **two columns** and **add another '-' sig**n to the result. Now i want to display these details in a **dropdownlist**. Also in another function I have to get the **selected value's first part**(first column of the table used to create the output) and store it in the database again. Query works perfectly.
Now my questions are,
            1) How to display final result in of joined columns in the dropdownlist?
            2)How to get the first column's value of the selected index of the dropdownlist?

Here is my code

```
public DataSet getSOCode()
{
    string strQuery = @"select  a.AGNTNUM+' - '+a.CLTADDR01
                        from AGNTDTL  a, cscsuboffice b, Web_User_Group c
                        where 
                        a.ARACDE=b.DESCITEM and
                        b.SHORTDESC=c.BRANCH and
                        a.DTETRM='99999999' and 
                        a.AGNTNUM not between '00050000' and '00200000' and
                        a.agntnum <'00300000' and
                        a.agtype not in ('PA','LG','BK') and
                        c.EMPID='000101' 
                        order by a.AGNTNUM";
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dwhConnString, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
}
```

This is the aspx.cs code

```
 public void loadSOCode()
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds = db.getSOCode();


     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
     {
            ddlSoCode.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlSoCode.DataTextField ="AGNTNUM" + "CLTADDR01";
            ddlSoCode.DataValueField = "AGNTNUM" + "CLTADDR01";
            ddlSoCode.DataBind();

            ddlSoCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select The Agent--", "--Select The Agent--"));

     }
}
```

Comment: It will be more clear if you add the current code that you are using.

Comment: @un-lucky, I have added the code. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Query like the following:

```
string strQuery = @"select a.AGNTNUM , a.AGNTNUM + ' - ' + a.CLTADDR01 as DisplayItem " +
                    " from AGNTDTL  a, cscsuboffice b, Web_User_Group c" +
                    " where .. // give conditions here
```

Then the code for binding will be :

```
ddlSoCode.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
ddlSoCode.DataTextField ="DisplayItem";
ddlSoCode.DataValueField = "AGNTNUM";
ddlSoCode.DataBind();
```

So that the `SelectedValue`  will give you the `AGNTNUM` and the combobox will display the combination of `a.AGNTNUM and a.CLTADDR01`

Comment: this is what exactly i wanted. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` with the combination of column names, in fact sql returns no column name in this case. Use alias to give a new name.

```
public DataSet getSOCode()
{
    string strQuery = @"select  a.AGNTNUM+' - '+a.CLTADDR01 AS NewColumn
                        from AGNTDTL  a, cscsuboffice b, Web_User_Group c
                        where 
                        a.ARACDE=b.DESCITEM and
                        b.SHORTDESC=c.BRANCH and
                        a.DTETRM='99999999' and 
                        a.AGNTNUM not between '00050000' and '00200000' and
                        a.agntnum <'00300000' and
                        a.agtype not in ('PA','LG','BK') and
                        c.EMPID='000101' 
                        order by a.AGNTNUM";
    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dwhConnString, CommandType.Text, strQuery);
}
```

and now use that column name to set Text and Value field.

```
public void loadSOCode()
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds = db.getSOCode();


     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
     {
            ddlSoCode.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlSoCode.DataTextField ="NewColumn";
            ddlSoCode.DataValueField = "NewColumn";
            ddlSoCode.DataBind();

            ddlSoCode.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select The Agent--", "--Select The Agent--"));

     }
}
```